# How to get the value of lost packets from ping with grep

Tags: linux

please help me I have result and it looks like this:`

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
300 packets transmitted, 300 received, 0% packet loss, time 299426ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.136/4.454/24.153/3.206 ms
```

`

I need search packet loss and I do:

```
ping -c 300 -q 192.168.1.1 | grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)'
```

and it's works but somtimes ping result look like this:

```
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
300 packets transmitted, 299 received, 0,333333% packet loss, time 299433ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.175/4.424/23.546/3.077 ms
```

then I have to use

`ping -c 300 -q 192.168.1.1 | grep -oP '\d+.\d+(?=% packet loss)`'

Is it possible to combine these two queries to display the packet loss results?Because I don't know when the result will be in a fraction and when as an integer

Comment: `ping ... |  awk '/packet loss/ { print $6 }'`

Comment: This is nice, but still you need to remove the percent sign to get what the poster required.

Comment: ok, thank you it works, but I have another question can I print result without percent sign, only value?

Answer (score 1):

You could combine them as "digit or dot"+. It is technically incorrect, but with ping it will do the job safely:

```sh
ping -c 300 -q 192.168.1.1 | grep -oP '[\d+.,]+(?=% packet loss)'
```

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regular expression with an optional group after the `\d+` that matches the fraction:

```
\d+(,\d+)?
```

The `grep` command becomes:

```
grep -oP '\d+(,\d+)?(?=% packet loss)'
```

Here comma is used as the decimal separator to match your example. If you want to match either comma or dot as suggested in a comment you can use the following fragment:

```
\d+([,.]\d+)?
```

If you only want to match dot then you have to escape it with a backslash:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Comment: Good solution. I would suggest including a dot (.) as well because the poster mentioned they use . in the regex, which is a bit of a mismatch with the data they posted.

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off using `awk` for something like this:

```
ping ... | awk '/packet loss/ { print strtonum($6) }'
```

Where

```
/packet loss/ - will apply only to lines that contain (the regular expression) "packet loss"
print - print the following expression
strtonum($6) - take the 6th field (fields are separated by white-space, by default) and strip off just the number portion
```